# Java: process annotation inherited from .class file

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I have an annotation that is inherited and has class-retention:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

It is used like this:

```
@MyAnnotation
public class Parent {}

public class Child extends Parent {}
```

If these classes are within the same project, my annotation processor is executed on both classes because the annotation is inherited correctly.

If `Parent` is in a separate project the .jar of which is included in the classpath of the project of `Child`, it doesn't work. The annotation processor is not executed on `Child`.

Is this by design or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How do you search for classes with that annotation? Please show us some code

Comment: @kalsowerus I don't search for them. Annotation processors define which annotations they want to process and are supplied with them automatically. It is a special mechanic built into the Java compiler.

Comment: You haven't specified, how you build your project. Do you use incremental compilation?

Comment: @user1643723 Eclipse compiler and full Gradle build yield the same result.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose, that's a limitation of Javac. It does not lookup annotation on binary classes bu default, so no wonder, that annotations, inherited from binary classes are also not returned. Note, that you can always scan for annotations manually by iterating over top-level classes and inspecting their parents.

Comment: @user1643723 But to invoke the annotation processor at all, the annotation has to be used at least once in the code, right?

Comment: @ErikHofer No. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html), — "If there are no annotation types present, annotation processing still occurs but only universal processors which support processing "*" can claim the (empty) set of annotation types".